# How to move tables from one database to another in SQLServer

Tags: sql-server

Sir,
     I need to move a table present in database1 to database2 in same Sqlserver. Will you please tell me how can I achive that?

Comment: Which sql server are you using? Is the data in the table related to other tables in the database?

Answer (score 0):

1- You can use Import/Export Util after right click on the database to transfer the table, after transfer succeed then delete from old database.

2- Generate SQL Script for creating the table, then use select into from clause.